# Keep Client IP using Istio and and Envoy sidecar with a custon nginx as load balancer

Tags: nginx, istio, envoyproxy

My setup is a regular Nginx (not ingress-nginx) as a Load Balancer and that load balancer points to a service that acts as api gateway. The problem is that now that I'm implementing Istio, the envoy proxy that is being attached to my nginx is deleting my clients IPs, so I can't use IP whitelisting withing the Nginx config file like:

```
allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
deny all;
```

Because my Nginx is receiving 127.0.0.1 from Envoy sidecar.

How can I tell Envoy to send my Nginx the real IP? or how can I handle IP whitelisting with Istio, without using an ingress component?

Comment: there's a relevant discussion on the github https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2659 and https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/4128

Comment: Did you try to set SocketOption within envoy bootstrap as described here https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2659#issuecomment-420487228?

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have defined Service, Gateway and VirtualService as below. I assume that you use istio default controller instead of nginx as you said that you use simple nginx not nginx ingress controller :

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5000
      name: http
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "primeratest.redacted.co"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
    hosts:
    - "primeratest.redacted.co"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  hosts:
  - "primeratest.redacted.co"
  gateways:
  - api-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api
        port:
          number: 5000
```

It will work if you add **externalTrafficPolicy: Local** to the istio-ingressgateway service, and then in your nginx conf add a header with **$http_x_forwarded_for**.

Setting **externalTrafficPolicy: Local** in the ingress-gateway service will cause the real client IP to be passed through.
Envoy does not have support for filtering **x-forwarded-for** , it would need to be added.

Filtering based on IP is discussed here also as a possible fix: [filtering-forwarder](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/179).

Useful documentation: [white-black-listing](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/).

Useful article: [whitelists](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/istio-ip-whitelists-1633acbd4205).

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant that I am not using any of the istio gateways (nginx or ingressgateway), I just have a regular nginx as load balancer and my requests are then forwarded to an API Gateway that distributes to the diferent services inside the cluster, and the problem now comes with the fact that the Envoy sidecar injected to my Nginx is removing my real IP from requests and puts 127.0.0.1 for my Nginx, so I can't whitelist anymore